# Extract block of text between a pattern text

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to extract a block of text between a block of text and failing to do so.

The block of text looks something like this

```
!###################################################################################################
!# Approved : YES
!# REASON: sample reason
!# DEVICE: device1
!# ACL: Acl_sample

access-list <Rule No> extended permMuramat esp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
access-list <Rule No> extended permMuramat udp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>

!##########################################################################
!# REASON:test
!# DEVICE: RTP
!# SECTION : Foundational

access-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
!######################################################################################################
!# APPROVED : YES
!# REASON: test1xxx
!# DEVICE: xxx test1 Devices
!# SECTION: test1
!# REQUESTER: test1@test1test2.com
!# Exp. Date : 8/2016

   access-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
access-list <Rule No> permMuramat <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
```

Basically get everything into an array list.

I was trying to follow a pattern where that starting index would be something which starts with a "!#" and the next character is not a "#" then this becomes the "Startindex" and the end index would be if the next character starts with "!" and the proceeding characters have atleast two "#"es.

Failing miserably though :(

The file is basically an rtf file. This is what my code looks right now.

```
string path = @"\\WDMYCLOUD\Public\data.rtf";

            string rtfText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            RichTextBox rtBox = new RichTextBox { Rtf = rtfText };

            var plainText = rtBox.Text;

            var charArr = plainText.ToCharArray();

            var arrBuffer = new ArrayList();

            string tmp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                int bufferIndex;

                var startIndex = bufferIndex = i;

                if (charArr[startIndex] == '!' && charArr[startIndex + 1] == '#' &&
                    charArr[startIndex + 2] != '#' && charArr[startIndex + 2] != ' ')
                {
                    for (int j = bufferIndex; j < charArr.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (charArr[j] == '!' && charArr[j + 1] == '#' && charArr[j + 2] == '#')
                        {
                            bufferIndex = j + 2;

                            for (int charStartIndex = startIndex; charStartIndex <= bufferIndex; charStartIndex++)
                            {
                                tmp = tmp + charArr[charStartIndex];
                            }
                            arrBuffer.Add(tmp);
                            tmp = "";
                        }
                        arrBuffer.Add(tmp);
                        tmp = "";
                    }

                }
            }
```

I get all sort of mess in the array list while I expect it to contain the blocks.

Expected output should be

```
  First Block:

    !# Approved : YES
    !# REASON: sample reason
    !# DEVICE: device1
    !# ACL: Acl_sample

    access-list <Rule No> extended permMuramat esp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
    access-list <Rule No> extended permMuramat udp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>

    Second Block:

   !# REASON:test
    !# DEVICE: RTP
    !# SECTION : Foundational

    access-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>

    Third block:

      !# APPROVED : YES
    !# REASON: test1xxx
    !# DEVICE: xxx test1 Devices
    !# SECTION: test1
    !# REQUESTER: test1@test1test2.com
    !# Exp. Date : 8/2016

       access-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
    access-list <Rule No> permMuramat <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>
```

Could anyone help me here?

Comment: So simply remove `!#{n}` where `{n}` is the number of # but not if followed by something?

Comment: You could use ReadAllLines to get an array of strings & go through the array looking for !######.......  replacing each with First Block:, Second Block: etc

Comment: Regex pattern could be [`string pattern = @"^!#{2,}(?=$}";`](https://regex101.com/r/LcGTUo/1) and then just use it's index + length to get the start of substring and then the index of the next match or end of the whole string for the end of a substring.

Comment: @m.rogalski This kind of works. I updated the regex fiddle with the data. You will notice the problem. Not all matches are being picked up.https://regex101.com/r/LcGTUo/2

Comment: @Navyseal Yes, in that case the pattern should be [`string pattern = @"^!#{2,}\s*(?=$)";`](https://regex101.com/r/LcGTUo/3) or [`string pattern = @"^!\s*#{2,}\s*(?=$)";`](https://regex101.com/r/LcGTUo/4). Beacause you have to include space character at the end and right after `!` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another approach:

```
string rtfText = File.ReadAllText(path);
List<string> loStringList = new List<string>();
StringBuilder loBuilder = null;

foreach (var lsLine in Regex.Split(rtfText, Environment.NewLine))
{
    if (lsLine.StartsWith("!##"))
    {
        if (loBuilder != null)
            loStringList.Add(loBuilder.ToString());
        loBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    else if (loBuilder != null)
        loBuilder.AppendLine(lsLine);
}

if (loBuilder != null)
    loStringList.Add(loBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: i think its just one # symbol in his separator code !# not !## but that is a good example

Comment: Okay, that's right. But "! ##" is the end index, maybe you can also use it as start index. Therefore different approach

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, what I did was to check each line if it contains a certain character, in your case "##", if it doesn't contain it, add it to your string/list.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"[..]file.extension");
foreach (string line in lines)
  if (!line.Contains("##")
  {
     //..
  }
```

Hope this helps somewhat.